# wrong save of float value PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sql-update, save

I have a problem with update or save of float value in my DB from PHP/Laravel.

Example:

> budget 166.0 -> FLOAT(5,1) in DB
>
> subscription_fee 7.5 -> FLOAT(5,1) in DB

This My code for operations:

```
foreach ($teams_ctrl as $team_ctrl)

         {
           $budget = $team_ctrl->budget;
           $budget-= $subscription_fee;
           team::where('id', $team_id)->update(['budget' => $budget]);
         }
```

Now the problem is that...the float value saved/updated in DB is 158.0 instead of 158.5.
I tried with floatval, with eloquent save/update....how can i save a right decimal value?